# Python 3. TTK. How to change value of the specific cell?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have some problem with `tkinter/ttk`.

So, i know how to get Treeview.focus, but how to change value of the specific cell in this table? Any suggestions?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

tview = ttk.Treeview(root)
tview["columns"] = ("SLOT_1","SLOT_2")
tview.column("SLOT_1", width=100 )
tview.column("SLOT_2", width=100)

tview.heading("#0",text="Column 0",anchor="w")
tview.heading("SLOT_1", text="Column 1")
tview.heading("SLOT_2", text="Column 2")

def add_item():
    tview.insert("","end",values=("","bar"))

def edit_item():
    focused = tview.focus()
    print(tview.item(focused))

tview.pack()

add_item = tk.Button(root,text="Add item",command=add_item)
add_item.pack(expand=True,fill='both')

edit_item = tk.Button(root,text="Edit item",command=edit_item)
edit_item.pack(expand=True,fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

I'm using `Python 3.6` with `tkinter/ttk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a thread so the program doesn't hang while it waits for the user to enter the edit. You'll probably want to add a text box or multiple text boxes for the edits to be entered

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import threading

root = tk.Tk()

tview = ttk.Treeview(root)
tview["columns"] = ("SLOT_1", "SLOT_2")
tview.column("SLOT_1", width=100)
tview.column("SLOT_2", width=100)

tview.heading("#0", text="Column 0", anchor="w")
tview.heading("SLOT_1", text="Column 1")
tview.heading("SLOT_2", text="Column 2")

def test_program_thread():
    thread = threading.Thread(None, edit_item, None, (), {})
    thread.start()

def add_item():
    tview.insert("", "end", values=("", "bar"))


def edit_item():
    focused = tview.focus()
    x = input('Enter a Value you want to change')
    tview.insert("", str(focused)[1:], values=("", str(x)))
    tview.delete(focused)

tview.pack()

add_item = tk.Button(root, text="Add item", command=add_item)
add_item.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

edit_item_button = tk.Button(root, text="Edit item", command=test_program_thread)
edit_item_button.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Two issues with your solution. `tview.insert("", str(focused)[1:], values=("", str(x)))` gets an error `_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "009"` it works when I change it to `tview.insert("", int(focused)[1:], values=("", str(x)))` but only up to 9 lines.  Line 10 already gets a value of "I00A" which results in error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '00A'`

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Gardener85's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44290159/11688889).

Using a single .item to update the line instead of adding a new line with .insert and then deleting the old line with .delete will help with a Treeview that contains more than 9 lines and keep the updated line in the same position in the Treeview.

Full code for modified [Gardener85's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44290159/11688889):

```
tview = ttk.Treeview(root)
tview["columns"] = ("SLOT_1", "SLOT_2")
tview.column("SLOT_1", width=100)
tview.column("SLOT_2", width=100)

tview.heading("#0", text="Column 0", anchor="w")
tview.heading("SLOT_1", text="Column 1")
tview.heading("SLOT_2", text="Column 2")

def test_program_thread():
    thread = threading.Thread(None, edit_item, None, (), {})
    thread.start()

def add_item():
    tview.insert("", "end", values=("", "bar"))


def edit_item():
    focused = tview.focus()
    x = input('Enter a Value you want to change')
    tview.item(focused, values=("", str(x)))

tview.pack()

add_item = tk.Button(root, text="Add item", command=add_item)
add_item.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

edit_item_button = tk.Button(root, text="Edit item", command=test_program_thread)
edit_item_button.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

To update only specific cell in TTK TreeView no need remove and re-insert as suggested. Instead call 'set' method of TreeView

```
tree.set(my_row_id, column=my_column_id, value=my_new_value)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Generally speaking yes, I agree. But I assume people also read question (or at least subject) and I really didn't find much to explain about one-line snippet :) anyway, added some text

Comment: Note for column "#0", use: `tree.set(id, text="My new test")`