# Tkinter dynamically display dictionnary content in Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program with 2 threads reading data continuously, and a third thread comparing the data read.

For the moment my third thread stores the data in a dictionnary of struct, the dictionnary key being the id of a specific data and the struct being like that :

```py
@dataclass
class dataValues:
    """Represents the different values of a data"""
    thread_1_value : int
    thread_2_value : int
```

Currently I have no GUI and everytime a data value changes, I store the change in my dictionary, clear my terminal screen and use print to display in the terminal every data whose value is different between the 2 threads.

I want to add a GUI and display them in a table containing 3 columns : The data ID, the thread 1 value and the thread 2 value.

From what I searched and understood, I can use tkinter to create a GUI, in tkinter use Treeview to create my table with its 3 columns. My problem is to link/bind the dictionary with the treeview.

Is there a way to create a link between a dictionary and a tkinter treeview so everytime the dictionary changes the treeview is updated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a link between a dictionary and a tkinter treeview so everytime the dictionary changes the treeview is updated ?

No, there is not. You will have to iteratively step through the dictionary and add items to or remove items from the treeview one by one.

Comment: For those coming here and looking for an answer, what I finally did is use queues to send the data to the GUI. This page : https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch09s07.html helped me understand the queues and this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197943/python-3-ttk-how-to-change-value-of-the-specific-cell how to modified the treeview